# Winbind PAM.D AD Groups, CentOS 5, Allow Only?

Tags: linux, centos, samba, pam, active-directory

I'm attempting to create a configuration, where users in specified AD groups can log in.  I'm having trouble stopping every AD user from logging in.  I've been doing this though `/etc/pam.d/sshd/` but is such a setup possible through `/etc/pam.d/login`?  Wouldn't that be a safer option?  I also really dislike `winbind`, and prefer the Kerberos+LDAP method, but unfortunately I'm not able to switch at this moment.  I appreciate any help, as I've been reading for a while and have not found solid direction.

These are the current pam.d configuration files,

#### `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

#### `/etc/pam.d/login`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       include      system-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
```

#### `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
account    sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup DOMAIN\Group_1
account    sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup DOMAIN\Group_2
account    sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup DOMAIN\Group_3
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM Winbind, is configured from this file, `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf`.

To restrict access to uers in specified groups, add this line
`require_membership_of = [SID],[SID],[SID]`

Replace the `[SID]` with the proper AD User, or Group, SID.  You can find out what users/groups are assigned which SIDs, with this command. `wbinfo -n [NAME]`

Replace `[NAME]` with the specified AD User, or Group, name.

However this entire winbind situation should not exist, as you should normally opt for the traditional Kerberos+LDAP method.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative, but on your Windows DC, you can install the Identity Management for Unix. Then for each user, you can right click > go to Unix attributes, and set whether they can login or not by setting the login shell from `/bin/shell` or `/bin/bash` to `/bin/false`

You will also need to add a line to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file:

```
winbind nss info = rfc2307
```

Hope someone will find this useful!